# Folders on harddisk not showing when using Add Reference (Browse) in Visual Studio in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: visual-studio

I just recently installed Server 2008 R2 and Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2. Then I added the Windows Media Services role and want to add a reference to Microsoft.WindowsMediaServices.DLL in

c:\windows\system32\windows media\server\Microsoft.WindowsMediaServices.DLL

I can see that the file and folder is there when using Windows Explorer, but when I open Add Reference and browse to c:\windows\system32, the "windows media" folder is not listed. There are also other sub-folders to system32 shown in Windows Explorer that are not shown in Add Reference.

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Add a reference to this file instead:

c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsMediaServices\v9.6\Microsoft.WindowsMediaServices.dll